# Can I (and how) lookup CDI managed beans using javax.naming.Context#lookup in EJB module?

Tags: java, glassfish, ejb, cdi, ejb-3.1

Can I (and if so, how?) lookup CDI managed beans using `javax.naming.Context#lookup` in EJB module?

I'm using GlassFish v3. I suppose that I can use `@Named`, but what is JNDI name of CDI managed bean? I want to lookup them from unmanaged POJOs so I can't use `@Inject`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can lookup the `BeanManager` via JNDI (`java:comp/BeanManager`) then use the JSR-299 API hung off of the `BeanManager` to get a contextual reference to a managed bean.

JSR-299 managed beans are not available for direct JNDI lookup.

Comment: I found a good code example at http://dominikdorn.com/2010/04/cdi-weld-manual-bean-lookup/

Comment: A named @ManagedBean(value="MyManagedBean") POJO can be looked up through JNDI with i.e. InitialContext.doLookup("java:app/myapp/MyManagedBean"); see API doc of javax.annotation.ManagedBean

Comment: I was curious about what `javax.annotation.ManagedBean` exactly is, here is a good answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/32420123/1341535

Comment: `@ManagedBean`:

`The ManagedBean annotation marks a POJO (Plain Old Java Object) as a ManagedBean. A ManagedBean supports a small set of basic services such as resource injection, lifecycle callbacks and interceptors.
Since: Common Annotations 1.1`

Answer (score 35):

You can also access the BeanManager by using CDI.current(), which saves you typing a good few lines of code. Example taken from [here](http://blog.chris-ritchie.com/2015/03/obtaining-reference-to-cdi-managed-bean.html)

Using CDI.current()

```
BeanManager bm = CDI.current().getBeanManager();
```

Using JNDI:

```
BeanManager bm = null;
try {
    InitialContext context = new InitialContext();
    bm = (BeanManager) context.lookup("java:comp/BeanManager");
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Now you have the BeanManager you can access your CDI beans by doing either a type-based lookup or a name-based lookup.

Type based:

```
Bean<CrudService> bean = (Bean<CrudService>) bm.getBeans(CrudService.class).iterator().next();
CreationalContext<CrudService> ctx = bm.createCreationalContext(bean);
CrudService crudService = (CrudService) bm.getReference(bean, CrudService.class, ctx);
```

Name-based

```
Bean bean = bm.getBeans("crudService").iterator().next();
CreationalContext ctx = bm.createCreationalContext(bean);
CrudService crudService = bm.getReference(bean, bean.getClass(), ctx);
```

Full example:

```
//get reference to BeanManager
BeanManager bm = CDI.current().getBeanManager();
Bean<CrudService> bean = (Bean<CrudService>) bm.getBeans(CrudService.class).iterator().next();
CreationalContext<CrudService> ctx = bm.createCreationalContext(bean);

//get reference to your CDI managed bean
CrudService crudService = (CrudService) bm.getReference(bean, CrudService.class, ctx);
```

UPDATE - This can now be achieved in one line if you are using CDI 1.1:

```
CrudService crudService = CDI.current().select(CrudService.class).get();
```

Comment: In my case I had to use `bean.getBeanClass()` instead of `bean.getClass()` to avoid WELD-001305 exception.

Comment: You could do CDI.current().select(CrudService.class).get() with  CDI 1.1+

Comment: How do I pass authentication credentials when using CDI.current()?  When using InitialContext() I can specify the Principal in the constructor properties.  How do I do something equivalent with CDI.current()?

Comment: Is it necessary to call CreationalContext::release when done using CrudService if CrudService is a stateless EJB?

Answer (score 0):

If you are working on a JSF / Jakarta Faces project and you're using [OmniFaces](https://omnifaces.org/), you can simply do:

```java
MyBean myBean = org.omnifaces.util.Beans.getInstance("myBeanName");
```

See also:

- https://showcase.omnifaces.org/utils/Beans
- https://omnifaces.org/docs/javadoc/4.0/org/omnifaces/util/Beans.html